# Why does my output change?

Tags: php, utf-8

I'm working with UTF-8 encoding in PHP and I keep managing to get the output just as I want it. And then without anything happening with the code, the output all of a sudden changes.

Previously I was getting hebrew output. Now I'm getting "&&&&&".

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are most common problems:

- Your editor that you’re creating the PHP/HTML files in
- The web browser you are viewing your site through
- Your PHP web application running on the web server
- The MySQL database
- Anywhere else external you’re reading/writing data from (memcached, APIs, RSS feeds, etc)

And few things you can try:

**Configuring your editor**

Ensure that your text editor, IDE or whatever you’re writing the PHP code in saves your files in UTF-8 format. Your FTP client, scp, SFTP client doesn’t need any special UTF-8 setting.

**Making sure that web browsers know to use UTF-8**

To make sure your users’ browsers all know to read/write all data as UTF-8 you can set this in two places.

*The content-type  tag*

Ensure the content-type META header specifies UTF-8 as the character set like this:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

*The HTTP response headers*

Make sure that the Content-Type response header also specifies UTF-8 as the character-set like this:

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8')
```

**Configuring the MySQL Connection**

Now you know that all of the data you’re receiving from the users is in UTF-8 format we need to configure the client connection between the PHP and the MySQL database.
There’s a generic way of doing by simply executing the MySQL query:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

…and depending on which client/driver you’re using there are helper functions to do this more easily instead:

*With the built in mysql functions*

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link);
```

*With MySQLi*

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")
```

*With PDO_MySQL (as you connect)*

```
$pdo = new PDO( 
    'mysql:host=hostname;dbname=defaultDbName', 
    'username', 
    'password', 
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8") 
);
```

**The MySQL Database**

We’re pretty much there now, you just need to make sure that MySQL knows to store the data in your tables as UTF-8. You can check their encoding by looking at the Collation value in the output of SHOW TABLE STATUS (in phpmyadmin this is shown in the list of tables).
If your tables are not already in UTF-8 (it’s likely they’re in latin1) then you’ll need to convert them by running the following command for each table:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

**One last thing to watch out for**

With all of these steps complete now your application should be free of any character set problems.
There is one thing to watch out for, most of the PHP string functions are not unicode aware so for example if you run strlen() against a multi-byte character it’ll return the number of bytes in the input, not the number of characters. You can work round this by using the Multibyte String PHP extension though it’s not that common for these byte/character issues to cause problems.

Taken form here: http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/how-to-avoid-character-encoding-problems-in-php/

Comment: how would you explain the fact that I had this working, and then, **without any changes made to the code**, I'm suddenly not getting the correct display. I finally got the characters to display properly, celebrated too soon, and now I'm getting the wrong output. What could have changed?

Comment: Is it just plain text file? Do you connect to database? Do you parse a file? You will need to write a bit more about this problem or share the file with us...

Comment: It's just plain text that I get from a user input form and run through a series of functions. I'm not connecting to a database or parsing a file.

Comment: Windows? What editor do you use? What browser? Is it online somewhere so we can see it? Can you share the code?

Comment: I'm working with Windows and using Notepad++ to encode the files in UTF-8 without BOM. I tried this in both Firefox and IE, and I got varying results. IE displayed the characters properly and Firefox did not. In any event, I implemented different steps (which I outline in my answer) to encode it in UTF-8 all throughout, and now it seems to be working again. Thank you very much for all your help, ljubiccica!

Comment: You are welcome. Maybe you just had the default encoding in FF wrong =)

Answer (score 1):

Try after setting the content type with `header` like this

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this function - >

```
$html = "Bla Bla Bla...";
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
```

for more - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Answer (score -1):

I put together this method and called it in the file I'm working with, and that seemed to resolve the issue.

```
function setutf_8()
    {
    header('content-type: text/html; charset: utf-8');
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    mb_http_output('UTF-8');
    mb_http_input('UTF-8');
    mb_language('uni');
    mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
    ob_start('mb_output_handler');
    }
```

Thank you for all your help! :)

Comment: Most of these settings are probably irrelevant to the problem. It's never a good idea to put together one "magical function" which "seems to fix problems"; much less propagate it for others to use. You should *understand* where your problem originated and apply a focused fix there. It's not magic, you know? [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/), [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: I realize that some of these settings might not directly relate to the specific problem I'm addressing. You can down-vote me on this for the sake of the community, and that's alright. In my case, I did this because I can't continue to develop the application till I can work with the proper characters, and I can't let this one issue impede me in further development. It's important that I work with a quick fix till I can complete writing the main functions that drive this application. When I'm finished, I would like to revisit and cut out any of the particular settings which are not "helping.