# Displaying hebrew strings in php

Tags: php

My code looks like this:

```
<?php
echo "בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ.";
```

The output in the webbrowser is:

```
×‘Ö¼Ö°×¨Öµ××©×Ö´×™×ª, ×‘Ö¼Ö¸×¨Ö¸× ×Ö±×œÖ¹×”Ö´×™×, ×Öµ×ª ×”Ö·×©Ö¼×Ö¸×žÖ·×™Ö´×, ×•Ö°×Öµ×ª ×”Ö¸×Ö¸×¨Ö¶×¥.
```

Which steps should I take to make the browser to show:

```
בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ.
```

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16766865/why-does-my-output-change. I was working with Hebrew when I asked this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell the browser that your page is utf8-encoded. This is done by setting the `Content-type`-header:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

Use `text/html` instead of `text/plain` if you want to print an html page.